# Replace part of string at specified position

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a part of string at specified position(start, end) by another string in javascript

Here is an example:

```
"Hello world this is a question"
```

I want to replace the part of this string starting at 5 and ending at 10 by "friends"

The output will be:

```
"Hello friends this is a question"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) calls and concatenation (`+`):

```js
var msg="Hello world this is a question";
var replaced=msg.substring(0,6)+"friends"+msg.substring(11);
console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

If you know the exact index you want to slice the string at, you should probably use javascript [string.slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp) method like so:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var part = str.slice(1, 5);
console.log(part); // "ello"
```

**Method 2:**

If you don't know the index, but you do know the string you want to replace, you can simply use [string.replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method like so:

```
var input = "Hello world this is a question";
var result = input.replace("world", "friends");
console.log(result); // Hello friends this is a question
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method

```js
var str = "Hello world this is a question";

console.log(str.replace(str.substring(6, 11), "friends"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` to achieve this.

```js
let str = "Hello world this is a question"

function replace(st, en, val) {
  str = str.slice(0, st + 1) + val + str.slice(en + 1)
}

replace(5, 10, 'friends')
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

there is replace function in javascript

```js
var replaceData = "Hello world this is a question";
  console.log(replaceData.replace('world', 'friends'));
```

Comment: the word to replace can appears multiple times and I only want to replace one